# Stub or mock instance method rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rspec, rspec-rails

The below function is a controller action and gets the data to be served from an AWS S3 bucket.

```
def show
    s3_response = Zlib::GzipReader.new(ApiBucket.bucket.object(id).get.body).read
  render json: s3_response
end
```

I am writing a spec for this method. I need to stub/mock such that `s3_response` doesn't actually request from s3. Here is what I tried. This doesn't work though. Please help.

```
describe '#GET show' do
  let!(:resource) { create(:resource) }

  before do
    json_data = Api::V2::Presenter.consume_as_json(resource)
    allow_any_instance_of(Zlib::GzipReader).to receive(:read).and_return(json_data)
  end

  it 'should return the resource in page format' do
    get :show, format: :json, params: { id: resource.uuid }
    response_body_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    json_data = Api::V2::Presenter.consume_as_json(
        Api::V2::ResourcePresenter.new(resource).page,
        true
      )
    expect(response_body_json).to eql(JSON.parse(json_data))
  end
end
```

I am getting this error `Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format`

Comment: Seems like `ApiBucket.bucket.object(id).get.body` makes the S3 request. You should probably stub that one.

Comment: I don't need to right? Whatever be it's response I am anyways stubbing `Zlib::GzipReader`.
So how does it matter?

Comment: Ruby still evaluates `ApiBucket.bucket.object(id).get.body` and passes its return value to `Zlib::GzipReader.new`. It then invokes that object's `read` method which returns the stubbed response. So stubbing `Zlib::GzipReader#read` doesn't prevent `ApiBucket` from fetching the raw data from S3.

Comment: Instead of doing that, wrote a private controller and then stubbed that function

Comment: Checkout AWS SDK doc https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/advanced-client-stubbing-in-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby-version-3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of stubbing `Zlib::GzipReader` or the `S3 Bucket`. One simple and easy way to handle such cases would be to create a new private function in the controller and then stub the controller function.

In the controller side:

```
def show
  render json: s3_response
end

private:

def s3_response
   Zlib::GzipReader.new(ApiBucket.bucket.object(id).get.body).read
end
```

The spec will be:

```
   describe '#GET show' do
  let!(:resource) { create(:resource) }

  before do
    json_data = Api::V2::Presenter.consume_as_json(resource)
    ResourceController.any_instance.stub(:s3_response).and_return(json_data)
  end

  it 'should return the resource in page format' do
    get :show, format: :json, params: { id: resource.uuid }
    response_body_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    json_data = Api::V2::Presenter.consume_as_json(
        Api::V2::Presenter.new(resource).page,
        true
      )
    expect(response_body_json).to eql(JSON.parse(json_data))
  end
end
```